# What is the appropriate way to filter a kendo grid with knockoutjs?

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, knockout-kendo

What is the appropriate way to filter a grid using the knockout-kendo [kendoGrid](http://kendo-labs.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/Grid.html) binding?

I am currently filtering a grid by binding it to a computed array, using the technique shown here: [Utility Functions in KnockoutJS](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html) - see "Filtering an Array."

```
self.filteredItems = ko.dependentObservable(function() {

    var filter = self.filter().toLowerCase();
    if (!filter) {
        return self.items();
    } else {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.items(), function(item) {
             return item.name().toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1;
        });
    }
}, self);
```

This works, however if you are not on Page #1, it does not reset the grid to page #1, so if there are less "pages" of results than what your search ends up with, the grid will be blank until paged to page 1.

To see the issue, 
1. go to this JSFIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/xW9yc/11/
2. go to page 3
3. enter "P" in the search input

Comment: Do you want the grid to start from page 1 when some filter is applied or just go to the last available page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the reference to the grid in an observable in your view model like so:

```
function ViewModel() {
    // ....
     self.grid = ko.observable();
}
```

and your HTML would be

```
<div data-bind="kendoGrid: {data:filteredItems, pageable: { buttonCount: 5, pageSize: 5 }, widget: grid }" />
```

Now, once the grid has been instantiated, you can reference it with `self.grid()` instead of `$("#MyGrid").data("kendoGrid")` - it's a looser coupling between your view model and your view because you don't have to hardcode a jQuery selector.

I've [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R4EPn/) to reflect these changes.

You can find the documentation for the `widget` option at the bottom of [this page in the Knockout-Kendo documentation](http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/Grid.html)

Comment: This is good - I don't see self.grid being set anywhere - how does that happen?!  I couldn't find any doc on the "widget" tag

Comment: @user210757 `self.grid` is just declared as an empty observable in the view model, and then in the HTML adding the `widget: grid` fills the observable when the kendo grid is instantiated. I used `grid` as a variable name - it could be anything you want though. I'll look for some docs on the `widget` parameter and post them here if I find anything

Comment: @user210757 See my edit to the answer for a link to the documentation

Answer (score 1):

If you are not averse to using the kendo javascript api, you can do the following :

```
var grid = $("#MyGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            if(grid)
            {
            grid.dataSource.page(1);
            }
```

[edited jsfiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/3CrMR/)

Hope this is of some help!

Comment: The only thing I am opposed to is the ViewModel interacting directly with the View.  The ViewModel probably shouldn't know about #MyGrid.  If there was a way to trigger this strictly from the View, that would work better. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: i would have accepted both answers if I could since it was a collaboration of the two that I used. this was definitely a huge help thank you